# Accessing a nested JSON key without looping

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have a JSON string like the one given below which is stored in `$json`. I want to access the first `category_id` without using a loop. How can I access it?

```
$json = '{"outfits": [{"1": [{"category_id": "women_jeans", "product_id": 464540467}, {"category_id": "women_tops", "product_id": 487351815}, {"category_id": "women_coats", "product_id": 493322686}, {"category_id": "women_bags", "product_id": 483902882}, {"category_id": "women_shoes", "product_id": 492772225}]}]}';
$outfits = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: You have multiple `category_id` available.. Which one exactly do you want to access?

Comment: @Nikola : first one which has product_id : 464540467

Comment: $outfits = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($outfits['outfits'][0][1][0]["category_id"]);

Comment: @RakeshSojitra, you can did this without the `true` element in `json_decode`.

Comment: yes you can do it. `true` will give you simple array without object array.

Comment: @Ruchish & @ Frayne : can you give answer for without loop and as a object ? I mean without true ?

Comment: without true check below frayne answer.

Comment: @RuchishParikh : Its using loop. I want without loop. actually i need random one outfit so i am asking for particular key.

Comment: Use $array = $outfits->outfits[0]->{1};
$category1 = $array[0]->category_id;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code.

```
$json = '{"outfits": [{"1": [{"category_id": "women_jeans", "product_id": 464540467}, {"category_id": "women_tops", "product_id": 487351815}, {"category_id": "women_coats", "product_id": 493322686}, {"category_id": "women_bags", "product_id": 483902882}, {"category_id": "women_shoes", "product_id": 492772225}]}]}';
$outfits = json_decode($json,true);
echo "Category 1: ".$outfits["outfits"][0][1][0]['category_id'];
echo "Category 2: ".$outfits["outfits"][0][1][1]['category_id'];
```

**Output**

```
women_jeans
women_tops
```

Also you can use below function to find particular value.

```
$array = $outfits["outfits"][0][1];
$key = "product_id";
$val = "464540467";

function whatever($array, $key, $val) {
    foreach ($array as $item)
        if (isset($item[$key]) && $item[$key] == $val)
            echo $item['category_id'];
    return false;
}

whatever($array,$key,$val);
```

**Output**

```
women_jeans
```

If you want to get category_id without loop and `true` then use below.

```
$array = $outfits->outfits[0]->{1};
$category1 = $array[0]->category_id;
```

Comment: Use above function to get first one which has product_id : 464540467. @Rakesh Sojitra

Comment: Yes i just forgot to write json_decode($json,true); TRUE. thats the issue.

Comment: You can do that without the `true`. [Check my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252027/how-can-i-access-category-id/37252438#37252438)

Comment: yes, that also can achieve and they need it without foreach loop as he has mentioned.

Comment: check edited code for without loop and `true` you can get first category value. @RakeshSojitra

Comment: @RuchishParikh: superb. Thank you for your nice answer.

Comment: Welcome... :) Glade to help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $json = '{"outfits": [{"1": [{"category_id": "women_jeans", "product_id": 464540467}, {"category_id": "women_tops", "product_id": 487351815}, {"category_id": "women_coats", "product_id": 493322686}, {"category_id": "women_bags", "product_id": 483902882}, {"category_id": "women_shoes", "product_id": 492772225}]}]}';
$outfits = json_decode($json,true);
```

Comment: Yes I just find my mistake at json_decode($json,true); anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Eg.

```
<?php
$json = '{"outfits": [{"1": [{"category_id": "women_jeans", "product_id": 464540467}, {"category_id": "women_tops", "product_id": 487351815}, {"category_id": "women_coats", "product_id": 493322686}, {"category_id": "women_bags", "product_id": 483902882}, {"category_id": "women_shoes", "product_id": 492772225}]}]}';
$outfits = json_decode($json, true);


$arr = $outfits["outfits"][0][1];
```

Direct access of values :

```
echo $arr[0]['category_id'].", ".$arr[1]['category_id'];

function walk($v, $k) {
    echo "$k : ".$v['category_id']."<br/>";
}
```

You can use **[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)** if you don't want your own Loop :

```
array_walk($arr, "walk");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json= '{"outfits": [{"1": [{"category_id": "women_jeans", "product_id": 464540467}, {"category_id": "women_tops", "product_id": 487351815}, {"category_id": "women_coats", "product_id": 493322686}, {"category_id": "women_bags", "product_id": 483902882}, {"category_id": "women_shoes", "product_id": 492772225}]}]}';

//convert json to associative array.  
$json_array = json_decode($json,true);

// Return the values from a single column in the input array 
$newArray= array_column($json_array["outfits"][0][1],"category_id");
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => women_jeans
    [1] => women_tops
    [2] => women_coats
    [3] => women_bags
    [4] => women_shoes
)
```

**Note**: array_column only available from **5.5+**

Answer (score 0):

> OP's Requirement *I want to access it without loop.* This is not
>   correct cause you have multiple `category_id`, So the question is
>   which one you need. So you need loop.

By using `json_decode` you will have an object array, so you need to do these. Let `$json` is your string. By using `$outfits->outfits[0]->{1}` in the foreach loop just get the last dimension of the resultant array, so its easy to access the `category_id`.

```
$outfits = json_decode($json);

foreach($outfits->outfits[0]->{1} as $val){
    echo $val->category_id."<br/>";
}
```

**Result:**

```
women_jeans
women_tops
women_coats
women_bags
women_shoes
```